# How to replace values that are less than 0 in multiple columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace all the values in my dataframe (for specific columns) that are `< 0`  with a value of `0`.

I have tried this code, but it does not seem to be working for me:

```
df.loc[df[['col_1','col_2','col_3']] < 0, 'col_1','col_2','col_3'] = 0
```

When using this line of code, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

I am not sure whether it is the code I am using that is halting me from accomplishing what I want to do.

Therefore, could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Thank you - please see sample data and expected output below.

**Sample data:**

```
col_1     col_2     col_3
--------------------------
  4         5        -1 
 -3        -4         5
  2        -2         2
```

**Anticipated Result:**

```
col_1     col_2     col_3
--------------------------
  4         5         0
  0         0         5
  2         0         2
```

Comment: When `df.loc[...]` gives you "'int' object has no attribute 'loc'", it means that `df` is an int at the time when the code has run. Have you checked `df`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pd.DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html#pandas.DataFrame.clip) to set all values below 0 to 0 (or the threshold of your choice):

`df[['col_1','col_2','col_3']] = df[['col_1','col_2','col_3']].clip(lower = 0)`

On your sample data this gives:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      4      5     -1
1     -3     -4      5
2      2     -2      2

In [46]: df[['col_1','col_2','col_3']] = df[['col_1','col_2','col_3']].clip(lower = 0)

In [47]: df
Out[47]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      4      5      0
1      0      0      5
2      2      0      2
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - but if I had like over 30 columns, and I wanted to use this method for only 3/36 columns, what would be the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: I think the same: just include a list of the 3/36 columns, instead of all of them. for example, in your dataframe if you wanted to only clip `col_1` and `col_3`, leaving the rest intact, you'd do: `df[['col_1', 'col_3']] = df[['col_1', 'col_3']].clip(lower=0)`

Comment: thank you very much for your help! It has been very helpful, thanks. :)